# app:cornerRadius doesn't work for MaterialButton

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components, material-components-android

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/button_tour"
            app:cornerRadius="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Take a tour"/>
```

I added a material button in my android project, when i try to set round corner using `app:cornerRadius`, i find it doesn't work at all.

Comment: give some height and width to your button

Comment: You can write style for this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use material theme .change parent of AppTheme in styles to some  material theme like`Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.`because **material components** require a **material theme**.

```
 <style name="AppTheme.Clinic" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: That works! Thank you so much! It has confused me a whole day.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
add this style for outline material button

```
   <style name="materialButtonOutlinedStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
    <item name="cornerRadius">10dp</item>
</style>
```

then add this style to your button:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/button_tour"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView"
    app:cornerRadius="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Take a tour"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

Create a new drawable source such as follows

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle">

     <corners android:radius="20dp" />

</shape>
```

and set it as background to your MaterialButton

Comment: The question is about MaterialButton - this answer is for classic Android Button